# how to automate pagination with selenium python?(without manually selecting the next button)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I am scraping a list of websites for images,using selenium webdriver+scrapy but the next button for each website has different class/div names,how to automatically find the next pages in different sites to scrape?

Comment: Please add a sample of your code and what you have attempted, it is difficult for most of the people to answer a question that is not focused enough. Also, please consider taking a look into: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic structure for pagination:

```
page_count = 1
while (nextbutton.isEnbled):
# Increase page_count value on each iteration on +1
page_count += 1
try:
    nextbutton.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # Stop loop if no more page available
    break
```